# Multiple data in a category in a spline graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to graph like the picture below.

[image]

So I tried to insert the data as I set it in the bar graph, but it failed.
I used two methods.

One.

```
// data: [YYYYMMDDhhmm, value]  
const sampleData = [[201906281815, 1], [201906281815, 4], [201906281815, 2], [201906281830, 10], [201906281830, 7], [201906281830, 15], [201906281845, 11], [201906281845, 8], [201906281845, 22]];
chart.series[0].setData(sampleData);
```

In the first case, the chart was drawn, but data in the same time zone overlap.
The time has been successfully inserted into xAxis.

Two.

```
// data: [YYYYMMDDhhmm, [value, value, value, value, ...]]  
const sampleData = [[201906281815, [1, 4, 2]], [201906281830, [10, 7, 15]], [201906281845, [11, 8, 22]]];
chart.series[0].setData(sampleData);
```

Time was inserted correctly in xAxis, but the spline was not drawn.

How can I create a chart like the picture I want to insert data into?

Comment: I would suggest you convert time to time in milliseconds since 1970, and use highcharts datetime axis. Then you can put the real time between the different points. Here is an example based on your data: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/s6wL1o2r/12/, but since you have 3 timestamps that are the same with different values, it draws them as lines.

Comment: @ewolden Thank you for your answers to my questions. In my actual code (not an example), switch to UTC and insert it into xAxis. And the data in the same time zone overlap as in the example given to me. I would like to create a chart with the array index in the fastest order, without overlapping the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preprocess your data to calculate accurate `x` position on `xAxis`:

```
var sampleData = [
        [201906281815, 1],
        [201906281815, 4],
        [201906281830, 10],
        [201906281830, 7],
        [201906281830, 15],
        [201906281845, 11],
        [201906281845, 8],
        [201906281845, 22]
    ],
    repeated = 0,
    newData = [],
    xData = 0,
    yIndex = 0,
    step,
    j,
    categories = [];

sampleData.forEach(function(el, i) {
    if (sampleData[i + 1] && sampleData[i + 1][0] === el[0]) {
        repeated++
    } else {
        step = 1 / (repeated + 1);

        for (j = -0.5 + step / 2; j <= 0.5 - step / 2; j += step) {
            newData.push([
                xData + j,
                sampleData[yIndex][1]
            ]);

            yIndex++;
        }
        xData++;
        repeated = 0;
        categories.push(el[0]);
    }
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: newData
    }],
    xAxis: {
        categories: categories
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4jfr1cgx/